# java program to calculate the average grades from x number of students using XML-RPC client

Tags: java, arrays, xml-rpc

the number of students is determined by the user by a "do you want to add another student" question, on the client class there must be just the input of the info (name and grades).

So far i managed to create a uni dimensional arraylist to set the number of students and their names using this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Object> estud = new ArrayList<Object>();
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String respt = "1";
            do {
                System.out.println("ingresa el nombre del estudiante");//ask for the name
                String nombre = sc.nextLine();
                estud.add(nombre);
                System.out.println("ingrese 1 para añadir mas estudiantes o cualquier otra tecla para salir");
//if the input isnt number 1 breaks the loop and continue with the next
                respt = sc.nextLine();

                System.out.println("******");
            } while (respt.equals("1"));
            break;
        }
```

But i cant manage to create a bi dimensional array to add the grades and send it to the XMLRPC server.

also i need to verify its working using postman.

Comment: You should start by creating a program in plain old Java (nevermind XML-RPC) that does what you are looking for. Once you have that, then you can add the XML-RPC layer to expose your program

Comment: yes, im starting with that i just mentioned XML-RPC because im not sure how to send the info but the major issue is the rest